# MX Records for Google Apps for Businesses Server + Another Mail server

Tags: mail-server, mx-record

I want to know if it's possible to have a Google Apps for Businesses account with say 2 emails  "hosted" there and also have 3 other emails accounts on my mail server. So can I set up the MX Records to "redirect" emails to the Google server first (highest priority MX records), if it doesn't find the destination email there, have it "send" to my regular mail server?

This way I can have 2 email accounts with all the "benefits" on Google Apps and 3 other not so important ones (like contact@, financial@ etc) on my regular email server, managed from my cPanel interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To anyone seeing this post, I'll answer my own question: yes it's possible. You need to set up "Split delivery" in your Google Apps account. More about this here: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173534